# Algorithm to determine sufficient range for numerical integration of PDF to get quantiles

Tags: algorithms, quantiles, numerical-integration

Given a probability density function (PDF), we want to use numerical integration to find a quantile at $\alpha \in (0,1)$.  Are there standard algorithms for determining a sufficient and optimal range over which to perform the integration?

Below is an example for a non-negative random variable parameterized by (*a, b*).  The problem is that the sufficient range depends on the parameters.  Extend the range too far and we are wasting compute; not far enough and we don't get correct quantiles.  I can think of various algorithms that dynamically look at how much probability mass has been summed and set subsequent step sizes accordingly, but I would be surprised if there are not canonical solutions for this.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import hyp1f1

def pdf(a, b, X):
    aa = 1/(2*(a**2))
    bb = 1/(2*(b**2))
    hyp1f1Res = hyp1f1(0.5, 1, (a-b)*X)
    pdf = (aa**(0.5)) * (bb**(0.5)) * np.exp(-X*aa) * hyp1f1Res
    return pdf

# Set the random variable parameters:
a = 0.5
b = 1.5

Xmax = 20   # Upper bound of integration range -- works for these parameter values, but not sufficient for others
dX = 0.001  # Step size
nSteps = int((Xmax-dX)/dX)
X = np.linspace(start=dX, stop=Xmax, num=nSteps) # squared radius to evaluate
PDF = pdf(a, b, X) 
CDF = np.cumsum(PDF*dX)

alpha = 0.9
idx = np.argmin(np.abs(CDF-alpha))
quantile = X[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

SciPy provides a generalized numerical interpolation of quantiles from a PDF in [scipy.stats.sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial.html), also described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/sampling_pinv.html).

Note that the quantile function is often referred to there as the "Probability Point Function" (PPF).